# Align input type range vertical middle

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have a div and one input and on this div I want to have the input everytime on every height on the middle vertical. What can I do?

Code here:

```
 <div class="buttons-player"> 
    <div class="range-video col-xs-6">
         <input type="range" id="progress-bar" value="0" />
     </div>
  </div>
```

Comment: Have you tried using something like this ; http://howtocenterincss.com/

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to vertically center text with CSS?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8865458/how-to-vertically-center-text-with-css)